# Android: create TextView from template file and append to existing TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a template of simple TextView, `simple_txt.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" >
</TextView>
```

And I have a main layout. There have I some other TextView:

```
...
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_text_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
/> 
...
```

So I need to create a few TextViews from template `simple_txt.xml` and append to *main_text_view* (simple_txt go after main_text_view).

I know that it's possible to add any view to layout (addView), but it adds a view inside of the layout, not next to.

How can I do this?

Comment: reuse UI in android try to search it in google

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your text view in another layout, e.g. LinearLayout.  Create your new TextViews using the LayoutInflater, then insert them into the layout that surrounds your original TextView.  Example:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/textViewContainer" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_text_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

And then

```
ViewGroup group = ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.textViewContainer));
group.addView (
     LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.simple_text, group));
```

Comment: what the difference between your method with ViewGroup and LinearLayout llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.textViewContainer);
Button btnNew = new Button(this);
llMain.addView(btnNew); ?? and question : can i create view from template file , do something with it (set text...) and then make addView() ??

Comment: I use ViewGroup because it is the most generic type that supports the methods needed.  This allows you to change the LinearLayout in the resource file to some other kind of ViewGroup without changing the corresponding code.  And, yes, if you store the result from inflate you can then set the text before you add it.